# Why does Single LINQ extension method create a query Select TOP(2)?

Tags: entity-framework

I was looking at my profiler and it seem that the Linq extension method `Single` selects 2 rows. So why does the `Single` LINQ extension method create a query `Select TOP(2)`? Shouldn't it be `select top(1)` instead?

Comment: `Single()` should query for the top 2; `First()` *should* only query for one. Are you sure you're not looking at a `Single` query?

Comment: @Gabe You right. I was looking at the wrong query.. what a shame :( but still.. would like to know why Single query for a top 2 ? it is because it need to know if it got more than one result ?

Comment: Yes, the only way to know if there's only a single result is to ask for 2 and make sure you only get 1.

Comment: Btw.. for the one that voted too localized... how this is too localized since LINQ and entity framework is used by many here ?

Comment: "too localized" is for questions that only apply to you. Odds are you're the only person who was wondering why `First` causes two rows to be selected. I fixed the question so it shouldn't get closed now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`First` only requests a single result. `Single` requests two results because it only returns a result if there is exactly one member of the result set. If there are zero or two (or more than two) it throws an exception, so it has to request at least two results.