# Does Linq2Sql generated sql contains Top or not when Single() is used?

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

When I execute a Linq2Sql query like

```
db.Items.Single(it => it.Id == 1)
```

Some insist that the generated sql is like

```
select TOP (2) [t0].Id, [t0].Name
from [dbo].[SomeTable] as [t0]
where [t0].Id = @p0
```

but what I get from Sql Server Profiler (and Linqpad's sql window, and VS IntelliTrace window) shows that the sql does not contains any TOP, just plain

```
select [t0].Id, [t0].Name
from [dbo].[SomeTable] as [t0]
where [t0].Id = @p0
```

Is it the Linq version that matters? I'm using .Net framework 4.0, and reference a 4.0 version of System.Data.Linq dll.

Comment: Is the `Id` field guaranteed unique?  If so, TOP would not be necessary to ensure only 1 record returned.  Can you try with a query that doesn't rely on uniqueness?

Comment: How did you get the query where TOP is used ? Can you please cite the reference where it is said that TOP is used.

Comment: @PinnyM using other non-unique fields produces the same sql, without TOP

Comment: @Marshal, one of my friend insisted that the TOP is used, and a google search gives me these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829314/why-does-single-linq-extension-method-create-a-query-select-top2 and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hr/adonetefx/thread/c71f6628-aa66-4db9-a6f9-fd888683f1fb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query is produced by Entity Framework which uses TOP(2) but the second query is produced by Linq-to-Sql which doesn't use TOP(2) and instead checks in reading logic if the result set contains more than one record (and abort reading in that case).

Comment: yes you're right, Entity Framework produces a TOP(2) while Linq-to-Sql produces no TOP.